# how to remove the parenthesis in regex javascript

Tags: regex

I am trying to remove the "()" parenthesis and  keep everything inside the parenthesis.

For example,

(example)

to this:

example

This is the regex I am using to output this result , (example)

```
var str = str.replace(/.*?(\([^)]*\)).*?/g, " $1,\n"); //(example)
```

How do I change this regex to remove the open and close parentheses?

Using JS + Regex? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this with your string,

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var str1 = "(example)";         
var str2 = str1.replace(/[\(\)']+/g,'')
alert(str2);
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

[] is used to create a character set. Your character set contains ( and ). So overall, substitute ( and ) with empty string.

Comment: I do have a character set something like this (example),(example)... I want to remove the parentheses though. Can I still use your regex to work

Comment: Why are you including an extra `'` in your character class ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "(example)";
var result1 = str.replace(/\(([^)]*)\)/,"$1");
var result2 = str.replace(/[()]/g,"");
alert(result1);
alert(result2);
```

Answer (score -1):

This function would do it:

```
function stripParenthesis(str) {
    var pattern = /\)|\(/g;
    return str.replace(pattern, '');
}
```

Syntax explanation: The pattern is (between the two /) is to match '(' or ')'. The parenthesis needs to be escaped using '\' the '|' is the or and the /g is for global replace